# How to make an animated wave in threejs

Tags: math, three.js

I am trying to make an animated 3D wave with Three.js and Points. It is kind of working. It is starting slow and then the applitude is increasing. But after some time it gets too high and unsteady.

This is how it should be looking. However after some time it is loosing it's shape. The problem is the decreasing period of the sine and increasing amplitude. But I am failing to fix it.

[image: How it is looking]

Here is some code.

**Creating of the points mesh.**

```
this.particleGeometry = new Geometry()

for (let ix = 0; ix < this.WIDTH; ix++) {
  for (let iz = 0; iz < this.HEIGHT; iz++) {
    let vert = new Vector3()
    vert.x = ix * this.SEPERATION - ((this.WIDTH * this.SEPERATION) / 2)
    vert.y = (Math.cos((ix / this.WIDTH) * Math.PI * 6) + Math.sin((iz / this.HEIGHT) * Math.PI * 6))
    vert.z = iz * this.SEPERATION - ((this.HEIGHT * this.SEPERATION) / 2)
    this.particleGeometry.vertices.push(vert)
  }
}

this.particleCloud = new Points(this.particleGeometry, this.material)
this.scene.add(this.particleCloud)
```

The initial generation is pretty good. But the updating is buggy.

**animate() code:**

```
render () {
  let index = 0
  let time = Date.now() * 0.00005
  let h = (360 * (1.0 + time) % 360) / 360

  this.theta += 0.0008

  this.material.color.setHSL(h, 0.5, 0.5)

  for (let ix = 0; ix < this.WIDTH; ix++) {
    for (let iz = 0; iz < this.HEIGHT; iz++) {
      this.particleCloud.geometry.vertices[index].y = (Math.cos((ix * this.theta / this.WIDTH) * Math.PI * 6) + Math.sin((iz * this.theta / this.HEIGHT) * Math.PI * 6))
      index++
    }
  }

  this.particleCloud.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
  this.updateGuiSettings()
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
},
```

`this.theta` starts at 0 and then slowly increasing.

Comment: Try using addition instead of multiplication, `y = (Math.cos((ix / this.WIDTH + this.theta) * Math.PI * 6) + Math.sin((iz / this.HEIGHT + this.theta) * Math.PI * 6))`. Why has the amplitude a factor of `pi` inside, this seems unnatural, you could just as well use `20` instead of `6*pi`. Could you try to make the theta update proportional to the elapsed time, i.e., `factor*(time-starttime)`?

Comment: Thanks, will try this, too

Comment: Sorry, did not correctly scan the groupings in the formula, the `6*pi` is inside the trigonometric arguments and thus correct.

Comment: This question is a bit old, but do you by any chance have the link of a live version of this effect? I remember there is an example similar to this on Three.js official site but I can't find the link to it. Seems many examples have been updated.

Comment: @IsilmëO. Sure: https://www.nextindex.de

Comment: Here's a related codepen version https://codepen.io/deathfang/pen/WxNVoq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it working with `(Math.cos((ix / this.WIDTH * PI * 8 + this.theta)) + Math.sin((iz / this.HEIGHT * PI * 8 + this.theta)))`

Now it is steady. However will tweak it maybe more.